# error handling in struts2: specific response

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts2, freemarker

I created specific ExceptionMappingInterceptor that should treat all the exception that occurs in the application.

```
public class DefaultExceptionHandlerAction extends ExceptionMappingInterceptor  {

@Override
protected void publishException(ActionInvocation invocation, ExceptionHolder exceptionHolder) {


    String message = "error msg";
    HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
    try {
        response.reset();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.debug("Could not reset the response");
    }
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        out = response.getWriter();
        out.print(message);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        LOGGER.error("IOException in printMessage : " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
    } finally {
        if (out != null) {
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
    }

}
```

All the actions are called via ajax so in js i have global error handling:

```
error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     // all other errors
     var contentDialog = $("<div/>",{ "id":"contentDialog"});
     contentDialog.html(jqXHR.responseText);
     contentDialog.dialog({
           title : 'Erreur',
           modal : true,
           zIndex: 8888,
           resizable: false,
           close: function(event, ui) {
             $(this).dialog("destroy").remove();
           },
           buttons:{"OK": function() {
           $(this).dialog("close");}}
     });
},...
```

Problem: all uncatched java exceptions are well treated and I enter in the error: function in my js. But if i force freemarker exception, I can see that we will pass by my specific interceptor but response status will be OK so ajax will not enter in the error: part.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: the question is, what does really trigger the `error` in ajax. Maybe your status SC_BAD_REQUEST isn't sufficient. You can try something : in your ajax callback, allways log in console the XHR. Execute your server part with a normal exception and a specific one. In both case, inspect the XHR in the console. You may discover some differences

Comment: I changed your tag because Interceptor tag has 4 followers while freemarker has 700, and this is about Freemarker

Comment: What if you try `response.sendError()` instead of setStatus ?

Comment: Looks Like the SC_BAD_REQUEST isn't sufficient. Visibly, all 5XX status fire the `error` in ajax. The bad request 400 may not trigger it.

Comment: Freemarker has its own exception handling.

Comment: in the case of java eception SC_BAD_REQUEST will fire the error event. Even if I add the freemarker own exception handling, my interceptor will be executed so why adding 2 things if I could treat all t he cases in a single place?

Comment: Because `Exception mappings is a powerful feature for dealing with an Action class that throws an Exception.`. Action class not freemarker template.

Comment: Aleksandr, in that case both specifics TemplateExceptionHandler and ExceptionMappingInterceptor will be executed. Why ExceptionMappingInterceptor  is executed if freemarker template exception occures?

Comment: TCHdvlp : when the freemarker exception occures, im not able to do response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR) since java.lang.IllegalStateException is thrown). I think that probnlem lies here.

Comment: Because it is in the stack.

Comment: I think the most efficient would be, at this point, if you go ahead and see what calls `Template.process` in Struts. That thing is responsible for handling the View exceptions, and for full-page buffering (if you need that). So what is it?

Comment: @Aleksandr OP says the FreeMarker exception goes through his interceptor. So then, I think, it's not only for Action errors after all. Maybe the problem is simply that the response isn't rolled back on FreeMarker exception by Struts.

Comment: After more tests: freemarker exceptions are now gonig only to the TemplateExceptionHandler and NOT to the ExceptionMappingInterceptor. I think that in my struts.xml something was not well configured. So now java exception are going only to the ExceptionMappingInterceptor and template exceptions to the TemplateExceptionHandler.